# Closed form formula of asset that incorporates another asset's interest rate on top of its own

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to find a closed form formula for the price of an asset $D$ that has the following properties:

1. The asset grows by some interest rate $\mu$ at every instant.
2. Another asset's ($B$) interest rate $\sigma$ is also added to the asset at every instant.

I came up with the following differential equation to express this (up to debate whether this is correct):

$$
\Delta D = D \mu \Delta t + B \sigma \Delta t
$$

Solving this for $D(t)$ without the $B \sigma \Delta t$ part would be easy (some exponential function) but this additive factor trips me up (sorry if trivial, uni has been a while). I have a feeling this can be done with the product rule just by looking at the shape of the formula.

Also, I know that $B$ grows according to some interest rate $\sigma$ so $B(t)=B_1 e^{\sigma t}$.

**Update:**

Here's my (almost certainly incorrect) attempt using the product rule:

We want to solve:

$$
\frac{dD}{dt} = D \mu + B \sigma \tag{1}\label{1}
$$

Let's assume $D(t)=u(t)*v(t)$.

From the product rule, we have:

$$
\frac{dD}{dt} = v \frac{du}{dt} + u \frac{dv}{dt} \tag{2}\label{2}
$$

Equating the first terms of $\ref{1}$ and $\ref{2}$, we can set:

$$
D \mu = v \frac{du}{dt}
$$

Substituting $D=uv$ we have:

$$
uv \mu = v \frac{du}{dt} \\
\frac{du}{dt} = u \mu
$$
$$
u = u_1 e^{\mu t} \tag{3}\label{3}
$$
Equating the second terms of $\ref{1}$ and $\ref{2}$, we can set:

$$
B \sigma = u \frac{dv}{dt}
$$

Rearranging, we have:

$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{B}{u} \sigma
$$

Substituting $B(t)=B_1 e^{\sigma t}$ (known from the original problem statement) and $\ref{3}$, we have:

$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{B_1 e^{\sigma t}}{u_1 e^{\mu t}} \sigma \\
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{B_1 \sigma}{u_1} e^{ \left( \sigma - \mu \right) t}
$$
$$
v = \frac{B_1 \sigma}{ \left( \sigma - \mu \right) u_1} e^{ \left( \sigma - \mu \right) t} \tag{4}\label{4}
$$

Combining $\ref{3}$ and $\ref{4}$, we have:

$$
D = uv = \frac{B_1 \sigma}{ \sigma - \mu} e^{ \sigma t}
$$

I don't like this for many reasons though. If $\mu > \sigma$ this will grow in the negative direction, which doesn't make sense. More interest should surely increase the growth of $D$, not decrease it. Also, intuitively I expect $\mu$ to appear in an exponential somewhere (it is interest, after all). Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system of differential equations is:
\begin{align}
\text{d}B_t&=\sigma B_t\text{d}t
\\[2pt]
\text{d}D_t&=(\mu D_t+\sigma B_t)\text{d}t
\end{align}
Define the process $X_t:=e^{-\mu t}D_t$ and differentiate:
\begin{align}
\text{d}X_t&=-\mu e^{-\mu t}D_t\text{d}t+e^{-\mu t}\text{d}D_t
\\
&=\sigma e^{-\mu t}B_t\text{d}t
\\
&=\sigma e^{(\sigma-\mu)t}B_0\text{d}t
\end{align}
By integration, we readily obtain:
\begin{align}
X_t&=D_0+\sigma B_0\left(\frac{e^{(\sigma-\mu)t}-1}{\sigma-\mu}\right)
\end{align}
That is:
\begin{align}
D_t=e^{\mu t}D_0+\frac{\sigma}{\sigma-\mu}(e^{\sigma t}-e^{\mu t})B_0
\end{align}
An interesting observation to understand the dynamics is that:
$$\lim_{\mu\rightarrow\sigma}D_t=(D_0+\sigma t B_0)e^{\sigma t}$$
This last equation is consistent with your initial dynamics: the process $D_t$ has a growth component equal to the continuous return generated by $B_t$, which for each infinitesimal unit of time generates a return equal to $\sigma B_t$. The "simple interest" earned between $0$ and $t$ will therefore be equal to:
$$\text{Rate}\times\text{Time}\times\text{Initial wealth}=\sigma\times t\times B_0$$
But this quantity is also continuously being compounded at rate $\sigma$, so that the final wealth earned from the second term is $\sigma t B_0e^{\sigma t}$.

Comment: Thank you! 2 questions:
$$
$$
1. How did you know to define $X_t$ with the $e^{- \mu t}$ term? Is this a common technique?$$
$$
2. Why did my initial attempt at using the product rule not work? Is it because I assumed $D$ to have a form that it doesn't?
$$
$$
I think there's a typo when you're calculating the limit: $e^{\mu t}$ should be $e^{\sigma t}$ on the RHS. The site doesn't allow me to make me <6 character edits though (silly rule IMO).

Comment: Thank you @AttilaKun. For 1, check [this answer](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/36657/20454), it might help. This is known as the method of [integrating factors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor). For 2. I guess that that is the reason, namely you assumed a functional form that is not the actual one.

Comment: I'm noticing now that my solution is the special case of your solution in case of $\frac{D_0}{B_0}=\frac{\sigma}{\sigma - \mu}$. Bit surprising to me.

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't be surprised. Your solution can indeed be written as a product of 2 functions of $t$ if $\frac{D_0}{B_0}=\frac{\sigma}{\sigma - \mu}$.